# Rake tests running very slow

Tags: ruby, windows, unit-testing, rubymine

After running some tests, I'm convinced there has to be something wrong with my setup (windows, rubymine and latest ruby versions). My times right now are:

```
Finished tests in 14.289817s, 0.0700 tests/s, 0.3499 assertions/s.

1 tests, 5 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Process finished with exit code 0
```

With 5 VERY easy tests (just checking if validation on empty fields works). The total time for these 5 unit tests is 160 seconds, over 2 minutes.

What could I do to improve this speed?

Here are the tests:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ItemTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'item attributes must not be empty' do
    item = Item.new
    assert item.invalid?
    assert item.errors[:name].any?
    assert item.errors[:description].any?
    assert item.errors[:image_url].any?
    assert item.errors[:rating].any?
  end
end
```

Comment: Buying a faster machine? No honestly - without deeper knowledge about your tests it's hard to tell.

Comment: Now I am impressed about the slowness. You are not even hitting the database. Could be that loading the Rails environment takes a lot of time. How long is a `rake -vT` running?

Comment: A little over 20 seconds. I just found that this could be related to running ruby on Windows. Is this true?

Comment: try a ```time ruby config/environemnt.rb``` that's the most interesting part (or measure it by hand if window$ does not have such a command)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is Windows.  We use JRuby on Windows and it actually runs faster than RubyInstaller(mingw) ruby on Windows but we do see very slow results when running test suites or starting a rails server.  About 1 minute for a single test run due to the loading of the Rails environment.
You have a few options:

1. Switch to linux / osx
2. Use spork to keep a couple rails environments pre-loaded for your tests.  Note that this isn't perfect but it will reduce your times substantially.  With this option you'll probably want to use minitest or rspec, I had trouble getting spork to work on Windows with testunit.  With spork you should be able to get your single test run time down to about 10 seconds.
3. Write as many of your tests to run outside of Rails, in other words to not require the Rails stack.  This will be very fast, you should be able to run a test in only a few seconds but as you could guess, it's hard to test a lot of things (controllers, views) outside of rails.  Works perfectly though for functions you've broken out into modules that already do not require anything from rails.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I wasn't aware when initially getting into it that rails ran so badly on Windows. I imagine the Unix based Mac environment allows it to run faster? I've decided to put off RoR until I have access to a machine that allows me to run rails properly. I guess this would be the main reason rails isn't more popular (in my personal opinion).

Comment: Yes, Rails and a lot of scripting type languages for that matter are written for *nix environments, so yes, Macs will work fine.  Windows is like an afterthought and especially with Rails it is drastically slower.  You'll save yourself a lot of time if you start off and stick with the environment that most Rails work is done in.

Comment: I have created a virtual machine (virtualbox) and installed linux on it. Test time is down to (a still not terribly great) 11 seconds from 32 seconds. I can see though that just about all things ruby run faster in linux even when done from software emulation.

Comment: Try using spork with it and I bet you can get it down to just a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

What's the rest of your gem stack?  Sometimes third-party gems are initialized by rails and will try to phone home (New Relic, Airbrake) which can inflate your test times (though probably not by this much).  If something isn't strictly required for your test suite, you should try to pull it into  the proper env group, or set `require :false` via bundler:

```
group :production do
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Startup time appears to be killing you, so you and I are probably in the same boat.  Between Jodell and Dark Castle a lot of this is covered already, but here's my nearly-whole list of things that helped, in descending order of efficacy.

1. Get a patched 1.9.3 with the 2.0 filesystem improvements backported.  The first gets 2x better numbers but I'm using the second because I felt the first was unstable

   - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/thecodeshop/WVA4N2lJoM4
   - https://raw.github.com/gist/3242245/5cdb932c0a544cfbb51fdee5759942d4d2c263f5/1-complete.diff
2. Set your GC options

   - http://snaprails.tumblr.com/post/241746095/rubys-gc-configuration (I'm using the last one)
3. Turn off collecting coverage data (My IDE kept volunteering this)
4. Run Spork, and `set SPEC_OPTS=--drb`
5. Turn off virus scanner (don't actually do this, it's only worth 10% for me anyway)
6. Double-check your Gems, delaying the loading of gems with require: false

6 didn't actually buy me very much.  The biggest thing we had wrong was loading Thin unconditionally (which pulls in Eventmachine, which 21 megabytes installed), but the next 3 on the stack were actually being used by RSpec.  I have not looked at network traffic, but Jodell is probably on to something there.